# Как отобразить в каталоге товары с ценой больше 0 в Woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Есть интернет магазин с огромным количеством товаров.
Заказчик еще подчищает свои склады, а пока все еще есть товары с ценой 0, временным решением, хочу скрыть эти товары из каталога.

Для отображения каталога использую шорткод

```
<?php echo do_shortcode( '[products limit="9" columns="3" paginate="true"]' ); ?>
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, решение данной проблемы. Или где почитать, куда копать, очень прошу помочь. Спасибо!

Comment: Нет в этом шорткоде управления по цене. Возможно будет лучше установить таким товарам "нет на складе" и не выводить их. Это стандартная настройка.